# does pandas have the feature to count the amount of strings that are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, group-by

Im not sure if I am wording the question properly but I have been looking for a little and havent found what I needed.

For example, given data like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yes |
| 2 | no |
| 3 | yes |
| 4 | yes |

is there anything in pandas that would allow me to sum up the entries that are yes and no and make a pivot table like:

```
Total Values

Yes    --> 3 
 No    --> 1
```

i have some data where the choices of the data are 5 options that are all strings and i would like to find out how pandas can sum them up and put in a pivot table to see how many people voted for each of the choices.

I have been trying to use the groupby() function and messing with the index and columns parameter but I have been getting datatype error codes

Comment: `df.groupby('Column B').count()` will do what you want.